# How do i move a pieces of data between two words if the data has a % percent symbol at the begining?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a log file looking somtheing like :

```
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 class AutoQoS-VoIP-RTP-Trust
                               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 class AutoQoS-VoIP-Control-Trust
                               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 policy-map AutoQoS-Police-CiscoPhone
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config-pmap)#
```

Now i have to look for all the lines begining with `%` symbol between the lines containing 
hash `#` and put it into another error log file.

if you consider the above then this should go into error log file.

```
   SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
     class AutoQoS-VoIP-RTP-Trust
                                   ^
    % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

    SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
     class AutoQoS-VoIP-Control-Trust
                                   ^
    % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

    SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
```

Comment: Are you supposed to include that last line?

Comment: all the lines containing `%` between lines with # and # even if it is the last line.all i have to include the lines with # and # and should have all the lines between them if it has got a % at the begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
sed 'H;/#$/!d;s/^/\
/;x;/\n%/!d;s/.//;x;s/.*//;x'
```

Since you want both the prompt before the error and after the error, that one includes both except for prompts that would otherwise appear both as the prompt after one error and the one before the next error to match your sample output.

It's a lot simpler if we include both prompts regardless of whether errors follow each other or not:

```
sed 'H;/#$/!d;x;/\n%/!d'
```

If you wanted only the prompt before the error, that would also be a lot simpler:

```
sed '/#$/!{H;d;}
     x;/\n%/!d'
```

---

Probably the best way to explain those is translate to a more verbose language like `perl`. In `sed`, the hold space is like a static variable that is initialised with an empty line, and the pattern space a variable which `sed` assigns in turn to every line of input. Something like:

```
$hold_space = "\n";
LINE: while ($pattern_space = <>) {

  <sed commands go here>

  print $pattern_space; # unless -n option is passed
}
```

The `H` command translates to:

```
$hold_space .= $pattern_space;
```

The `d` command translates to:

```
next LINE;
```

That is stop executing the commands, discard the pattern space and start fresh with the next line of input.

`x` swaps pattern and hold space:

```
($pattern_space, $hold_space) = ($hold_space, $pattern_space);
```

So that last `sed` command translates to:

```
$hold_space = "\n";
LINE: while ($pattern_space = <>) {

  if (! ($pattern_space =~ /#$/)) { # anything other than a prompt
    $hold_space .= $pattern_space;
    next LINE;
  }

  ($pattern_space, $hold_space) = ($hold_space, $pattern_space);

  if (! ($pattern_space =~ /\n%/)) {
    next LINE;
  }

  print $pattern_space;
}
```

Which can be re-written in a more legible fashion as:

```
LINE: while ($pattern_space = <>) {

  if ($pattern_space =~ /#$/)) {
    if ($hold_space =~ /\n%/)) {
      print $hold_space;
    }
    $hold_space = $pattern_space;
  } else {
    $hold_space .= $pattern_space;
  }
}
```

Rename `$pattern_space` to `$line` and `$hold_space` to `$current_block` and it becomes even more legible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephane it works like a charm. it seems very easy for you but i find data exchange between hold space and space bit tricky.i havn't used them much as well.i was wondering if you could explain any one of the examples...-:).Still trying to understand this anyway

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
BEGIN {
    err=0
}
/^SWE.*#$/ {
    if (err) {
        printf "%s\n%s", txt, $0
        txt=""
        err=0
    } else {
        txt=$0
    }
    next
}
/^% Invalid/ {
    err=1
    txt=txt "\n" $0
    next
}
{
    txt=txt "\n" $0
}
END {
    print ""
}
' "$1"
```

Result:

```
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 class AutoQoS-VoIP-RTP-Trust
                               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 class AutoQoS-VoIP-Control-Trust
                               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
```

---

As an alternative, how I tought it was with extra lines to group:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    i = 0
    sep="------------------------------------------------"
}
/^% Invalid/ {
    printf "%s %3d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
    sep, ++i, txt, $0, sep
    txt=""
    next
}
/^SWE.*#$/ {

    txt=$0
    next
}
txt != "" {
    txt=txt "\n" $0
}
' "$1"
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------------   1
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 class AutoQoS-VoIP-RTP-Trust
                               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------   2
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01(config)#
 class AutoQoS-VoIP-Control-Trust
                               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
------------------------------------------------
```